# How to simplify the code of two similar methods?

Tags: java, refactoring

I would like to refactor these two methods which are practically the same except for a "maxResult ()", these 2 methods refer to two different gets, one that returns me the single user and one that returns the list instead. How could I simplify these two methods (always if it makes sense)
these are the 2 methods:

**First Method**:

```
public List findFirstByTransactionId(String transactionId) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> root = criteria.from(User.class);
        criteria.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get(User_.transactionId), transactionId));
        criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(root.get(User_.date)));
        TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery(criteria).setMaxResults(1);
         return query.getSingleResult();
```

**Second Method**:

```
public List<User> findAllByTransactionId(String transactionId) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> root = criteria.from(User.class);
        criteria.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get(User_.transactionId), transactionId));
        criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(root.get(User_.date)));
        TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery(criteria);
         return query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Make a third method with a parameter to decide whether to `setMaxResults`.

Comment: add a parameter to `setMaxResults`, or add `setMaxResults` with a condition evaluation

Comment: Or pass a boolean, if it's true you do the `maxResult` thing.

Comment: If your first method should only return a single entry shouldn't the return type be just `User` and not `List<User>`? And if the second method returns all Users shouldn't the name be different than `findFirst`?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS You're right by mistake I wrote the same method twice, to be fair I change! Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the easiest option usually is to try to move the code that is the same to its own method. Here, you have multiple options, one of them could be something like this:

1. Write a new (private) method:

```java
private List<User> findFirstByTransactionId(String transactionId, boolean onlyOneResult) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> root = criteria.from(User.class);

    criteria.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get(User_.transactionId), transactionId));
    criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(root.get(User_.date)));
    TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery(criteria);

    if (onlyOneResult) {
        query = query.setMaxResults(1);
    }
    
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

And then refactor your existing methods like this:

```java
public List<User> findFirstByTransactionId(String transactionId) {
    return findFirstByTransactionId(transactionId, false);
}
```

```java
public List<User> findFirstByTransactionId(String transactionId) {
    return findFirstByTransactionId(transactionId, true);
}
```

Now you eliminated 8 lines of duplicate code :)

Answer (score 1):

More of an addendum.

The other answers suggesting to add a boolean parameter are valid, but: clean coding advises to always strive for minimal count of parameters. And especially such boolean parameters are discouraged. Of course, it still makes sense here to do it that way, to avoid code duplication.

But what I would do:

- yes, **internally** have a `private List<User> findFirstByTransactionId()` taking a boolean parameter
- but on your **public** interface, simply offer TWO different methods, like `public List<User> findFirstUserByTransactionId()` and `public List findUsersByTransactionId()``

Those two public methods can then call the internal method and pass `true`/`false`. Using a boolean to make that decision is an implementation detail, and you should avoid making that visible on the public side of things.

Answer (score 0):

The methods you call on `query` work just like any other methods, so you can just put some of the calls inside an `if` block like this:

```
public List<User> findByTransactionId(String transactionId, boolean onlyFirst) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> root = criteria.from(User.class);
    criteria.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get(User_.transactionId), transactionId));
    criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(root.get(User_.date)));
    TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery(criteria);
    if (onlyFirst) {
      query=query.setMaxResults(1);
    }
    return query.getResultList();
}
```